# Linear combination of the identity and function with nonnegative derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given a arbitrary often differentiable functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that $f'(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ holds.

Define the function $$g\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},x\mapsto t\cdot x+(1-t)\cdot f(x)$$ for $0< t\le 1$

Is $g$ always bijective with differentiable inverse?

Comment: It would improve the Question if you include your thoughts about how to approach it, esp. any difficulty you encountered as a result.  For example, what conditions do you know about continuous bijective real functions?

Comment: hint: $g(x)\to \pm \infty$ for $x\to\pm\infty$ implies subjectivity. $g'\ge t > 0$ implies injectivity. Now, $g$ self is differentiable. What do you know about the derivative of it's inverse?